# PHP-FPM service status `stop/waiting` but workers are running?

Tags: php-fpm, start-stop-daemon, ubuntu-14.04

Starting php5-fpm appears to work, but checking the status immediately shows that it is not running:

```
[root@server ~]# service php5-fpm start
php5-fpm start/running, process 4516

[root@server ~]# service php5-fpm status
php5-fpm stop/waiting
```

Even though I am able to load PHP pages (meaning that PHP-FPM must be running), the status sometimes reports as `stop/waiting`.

It appears that there *are* processes running, but are these only the worker processes?

```
ps -aux |grep php
www-data  3552  0.0  0.7 338108 14960 ?        S    05:43   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  3553  0.0  1.3 338168 27156 ?        S    05:43   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  3554  0.0  1.1 337948 23020 ?        S    05:43   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  3555  0.0  1.0 334108 20644 ?        S    05:43   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  3556  0.0  1.1 337952 23032 ?        S    05:43   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

I'm concerned that the master process is not working correctly. There is nothing being reported in the PHP-FPM log though.

```
[root@server ~]# tail /var/log/php5-fpm.log
[03-May-2014 06:19:32] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Is `service php-fpm status` misreporting? Or is the master process actually stopped?

UPDATE: Rebooting the server causes PHP-FPM to start on boot and show as running, but issuing the reload or restart command causes it to go into the state described above. In it's current condition, I have to reboot the server every time I change php.ini. The server is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks for the system restart trick! That helped me. But I'm not having the issue happen again when I restart php5-fpm.

Answer (score 14):

It's a confirmed [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1242376) in Ubuntu's PHP-FPM. For me, the following helped:

1. `sudo service php5-fpm stop`
2. `ps aux |grep php`
3. `kill [list of proccess IDs echoed by the command above]`
4. `sudo service php5-fpm start`

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and for me it turned out to be a typo in one of the nginx configuration files.  I had tried to comment something out in

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

With a : instead of a ;

Comment: Configuration can be tested for syntax errors like this! `nginx -t` and `php5-fpm -t`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when trying to add a new conf file in fpm pool directory. Didn't realize that I'm using the same .sock name for two files. Just verify:

```
listen = /var/run/[NAME].sock
```